# Integrity constraint violation - How to create Entitys in Doctrine with Class Table Inheritance

Tags: php, mysql, inheritance, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a problem with creating inheritance Objects in doctrine... I´m using doctrine now for the first time...

Some details:
The sql database: 
[SQL](http://pastebin.com/WRjktJrV)

The DescribableVersionedEntity is the Superclass (Inheritance type Joined), which every Entity inheritances from. (So I have to use the Class Inheritance, yes?)

The Entitys:

[Entitys](http://pastebin.com/U3aDyBxx)

The executing Code:

```
$owner = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('ChecklistCore\Entity\Owner')->find(3);
$layout = new Layout();
//Add some Attributes... (not listed here)
$layout->owner = $owner;

$translLayout = new Translation($layout);
$translLayout->text = "Translation Layout";

$cl = new Checklist($layout);
$cl->changeNoteComment = "new ChecklistComment";
$cl->owner = $owner;
$translChecklist = new Translation($cl);
$translChecklist->text = "Translation Checklist";

$userChapter = new UserChapter($cl);
$userChapter->owner = $owner;
$userChapter->isActive = true;
$translUserChapter = new Translation($userChapter);
$translUserChapter->text = "Translation UserChapter";
```

And the Error SQL/Message:

File:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\ChecklistSystem\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php:91
```

Message:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO translation (language, text, describableVersionedEntity) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "Translation UserChapter", null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'describableVersionedEntity' cannot be null
```

I have read, that the foreign key (for example in UserChapter) have to link to the Top - to the first Parent.
In my example the inheritance route is:

```
DescribableVersionedEntity->ChecklistElement->Chapter->UserChapter
```

So I have 3 abstract "parent" classes and the last one is the usable Object, the UserChapter. How you can see in the SQL, I have create for each Entity a table and use the inheritance type "Joined".

So the next question: Do I have to declare in doctrine the next-top Entity or the top-of-the-top Entity as foreign key?

```
next-top: UserChapter(FK_UserChapter_Chapter), Chapter(FK_Chapter_ChecklistElement), ChecklistElement(FK_ChecklistElement_DVE) or

top-of-the-top: UserChapter(FK_UserChapter_DescribableVersionedEntity)
```

I think I have to use the top-of-the-top, cause I don´t need to create an Chapter Object for example (if then an UserChapter Object)

**So:** is my architecture in doctrine compatible to the MySql database? If yes - why is there a problem by creating a translation, cause the describableVersionedEntity is null??

I hope someone can help me, I couldn´t find a matching solutions to my problem in stackoverflow..
I´m pretty sure it´s a key problem...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: From looking at your error message `Integrity constraint violation: 10480` this is happening because there are some rules setup in the database to enforce the values in that field. You will always need to provide a valid `describableVersionedEntity` value or it won't work.

Comment: Yes that´s right, but i thought that doctrine creates for me the     describableVersionedEntity by setting up the inheritance type. So for example by creating the     layout and the neccessary     describableVersionedEntity there occurs no error... (See in the executing code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `UserChapter` class to `DiscriminatorMap` of `DescribableVersionedEntity`.

```
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"describableversionedentity" = "DescribableVersionedEntity", "checklist" = "Checklist", "layout" = "Layout", "checklistelement" = "ChecklistElement", "footnote" = "Footnote", "contentelement" = "ContentElement", "userchapter" = "UserChapter"})
```

The rule is that the root class of inheritance (`DescribableVersionedEntity`) has to contain all the subclasses in `DiscriminatorMap` - not only the direct ones. Subclasses doesn't define `DiscriminatorMap` even if they are bases for other classes. So move `DiscriminatorMap` contents from `ChecklistElement` to the root class - `DescribableVersionedEntity`

Comment: aaaah thanks!! Yes that was the problem... thanks, i forgott that.. 1 day error searching for nothing :P